# What disease does my Spinach have?

Tags: diseases, fungus, aphids, leaf-vegetables, spinach

My spinach has some kind of black mold. I cant find anything about black molds on spinach on the internet, so maybe you could help me identify the illness of my spinach.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's funny how the aphids triggered the development of new root systems along the trunk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because the black parts are blurry, but your "mold" looks suspiciously like [aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid). I think I can see at least one specimen that's clear enough to see the legs (in the 2nd picture). And that's a frequent kind of unwelcome visitor on spinach.

Please look closely and check whether the black spots are in fact small insects. A magnifying lens and a toothpick can be helpful if you are not experienced enough to recognize aphids immediately.

If you can confirm my remote id, note that you can find lots of Q/As here on the site about aphid control, but if you plan to eat your spinach, you are a bit more limited. My method of choice for edible plants is a solution of old fashioned hard soap in water (grated finely and dissolved in lukewarm water, if you use the right kind, it's not really a problem for the environment), other members here prefer neem.

Comment: You are right, they are black aphis. I had a look through the Internet and started treating the plant with citric acid this morning. It seems like to be working since there were a lot less aphids on the plant this evening. Thank you for you help!